# Change glyphicon depending on if collapse element is opened - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering how can I change glyphicon depending on if collapse element is opened.

So far I've got this code:

```
    <div class="jumbotron ref" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-11">

<a target="_blank" href="#"><h4 align="center">Click me.</h4></a>

</div>

<div class="col-md-1">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"> <!-- part to change-->
```

```
<div id="collapse" class="collapse">
<p style="margin-top: 75px;" align="center"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the messy code, seems like it likes to take away bits of my code. Just don't pay much attention to missing divs

Answer (score 0):

`.jumbotron` gets the class `.collapsed` when you collapse the menu. You can use that class to target the glyph.

You should also add `.collapsed` to the `.jumbotron` by default since the default state is collapsed, but the class isn't applied until you click to trigger it to be collapsed.

```css
.jumbotron.collapsed .glyphToChange {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron ref collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-11">

      <a target="_blank" href="#"><h4 align="center">Click me.</h4></a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">

      <span class="glyphicon glyphToChange glyphicon-chevron-down">glyph</span>


      <div id="collapse" class="collapse">
        <p style="margin-top: 75px;" align="center"></p>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A jquery solution using toggleClass.

```
$( ".jumbotron" ).click(function() {
  $( ".glyphicon" ).toggleClass( glyphicon-chevron-down, glyphicon-chevron-up );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the collapse events.

1. **show.bs.collapse**    This event fires immediately when the show
   instance method is called.
2. **shown.bs.collapse**   This event is fired
   when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait
   for CSS transitions to complete).
3. **hide.bs.collapse**    This event is
   fired immediately when the hide method has been called.
4. **hidden.bs.collapse**  This event is fired when a collapse element has
   been hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to
   complete).

```js
$('#collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(".glyphicon.glyphToChange").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
}).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(".glyphicon.glyphToChange").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron ref collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-11">

      <a target="_blank" href="#"><h4 align="center">Click me.</h4></a>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">

      <span class="glyphicon glyphToChange glyphicon-chevron-down">glyph</span>


      <div id="collapse" class="collapse">
        <p style="margin-top: 75px;" align="center"></p>

      </div>
```